# Map from T to T

Tags: java, scala, generics

Say you want to use a `Map` and you have the following requirement: you want each key to map to a value of the same type.

```
Map<???> map = ...;
map.put(42, 15);
map.put("hello world", 15); // compile time error, because you cannot map from string to int.
map.put("hello world", "foobar");
map.put(new Foo(), new Foo());
Integer i = map.get(42);
String s = map.get("hello world");
Foo f = map.get(new Foo());
```

Of course the above code will not compile but the trick is that you map from `T` to `T` where `T` is not defined at instantiation. The map simply returns the same type as the parameter. Of course it could be made more fun, like mapping from `T` to `List<T>`. Is this without ugly casting?

Scala's type system is generally considered more advanced, is there a solution in Scala?

If the answer to both of the above questions is no, is there any language that supports such typing?

Note:
Map in the above code is just an example of a type that takes two generic parameters. I'm not interested in Map in particular, but more in the type system.

Comment: I added put calls, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So...you want a `Map` data structure that holds *whatever* you like as a key and a value?

Comment: [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is a Scala library that provides a type that's kind of like this (it's a little more general) called [`HMap`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps).

Comment: I have no idea what it is you want now.  Using a `Map` data structure to hold arbitrary objects is possible but you earn a lot of horrendous-looking casts.  Perhaps you should be clear:  **why do you want to do something like this?** This sort of operation doesn't make much sense to me the way you're presenting it.

Comment: This is actually impossible in Java (even if you were to write your own class with generic methods), or at least the compiler error you want is impossible. Since `String` and `Integer` have a common supertype, somebody can do `map.put((Object)"hello world",(Object)15)` and type inference is allowed to see this relationship as well. I would instead suggest you take a look at what you're trying to do (what problem do you want to solve/why do you need this?) and think of a different way to approach it. (Unless Scala *can* do this, which I don't know, and you can use Scala.)

Answer (score 3):

*It's not precisely what you're describing, but a well-known pattern in Java is the typesafe heterogeneous container ([Effective Java Item 29](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~mmh/APD/bloch/generics.pdf#page=34)), which maps a `Class<T>` to an instance of `T`.  [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides a [`ClassToInstanceMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) interface that implements this pattern.*

---

In Java, you can jury-rig the type you are describing, but it won't be pretty.

```
public class TTMap extends ForwardingMap<Object, Object> {
  private final HashMap<Object, Object> delegate = new HashMap<>();
  @Override
  protected Map<Object, Object> delegate() {
    return delegate();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> T getType(T key) {
    return (T)delegate().get(key);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <T> T putType(T key, T value) {
    return (T)delegate().put(key, value);
  }

  @Override @Deprecated
  public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    Preconditions.checkState(key == value || value.getClass().equals(key.getClass()));
    return delegate.put(key, value);
  }

  @Override @Deprecated
  public void putAll(Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> map) {
    standardPutAll(map);
  }
}
```

This uses a [`ForwardingMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html) to give you a `Map<Object, Object>` but with the runtime constraint that keys and values will always be of the same type.  You need to use `getType()` and `putType()` to avoid the risk of runtime errors; `put()` and `putAll()` can only enforce this constraint with runtime exceptions.  You could also add a `putAll(TTMap)` method, if you wanted.

The `key == value` check in `put()` allows `null`s as long as both `key` and `value` are null.  If only one or the other is, you'll get a `NullPointerException` at the class equality check.

Also note @Radiodef's comment - every type extends `Object`, so there's no way - with generics - to prevent two types from being cast as `Object` and inserted.  You'll need additional runtime checks to address that.

If implementing `Map` isn't a requirement, you could follow a similar pattern (a private `Map<Object, Object>` and typed getters and setters) on a new class fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can require same type for key and value when putting them into Map. This wrapper should work (all ugliness is hidden inside and behaviour is typesafe, but types should be completely equal to avoid inferring a common supertype):

```
class HHMap { 
  val map = Map[Any, Any]()
  def put[T, U](k: T, v: U)(implicit ev: T =:= U) = map.put(k, v).asInstanceOf[Option[T]]
  def get[T](k: T) = map.get(k).asInstanceOf[Option[T]]
}

scala> val m = new HHMap
m: HHMap = HHMap@101f4db4

scala> m.put(5,6)
res8: Option[Int] = None

scala> m.put(5,"a")
<console>:13: error: Cannot prove that Int =:= String.
              m.put(5,"a")
                   ^

scala> m.put("b","a")
res10: Option[String] = None
```

If you want to get rid of `asInstanceOf` completely, see [`HMap`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps) from Shapeless2:

```
class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit def TtoT[T] = new BiMapIS[T, T]
val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> 23, "bar" -> "foo")

scala> val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> 23, "bar" -> "foo")
hm: shapeless.HMap[BiMapIS] = shapeless.HMap@764f8d21

scala> val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> 23, "bar" -> 99)
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev1: BiMapIS[String,Int]
   val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> 23, "bar" -> 99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with an implicit evidence parameter:

```
trait MyMap {
  def put[A, B](key: A, value: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B): Unit
  def get[A](key: A): A
}

val map: MyMap = ...
map.put(5, 8) // OK
map.put(5, "h") // Compile error
map.put("abc", "def") // OK
```

`A =:= B` states that the two types `A` and `B` must be the same type.